# Connecting WordPress.com site to Github?

Tags: wordpress, github, wordpress.com

I volunteered to work on a WordPress site recently. The site owners have some customizations they want on the site which might only be possible with custom coding, so I thought of connecting the site to Git Hub to track changes. However, they accidentally subscribed to a business plan on WordPress.com. I'm quite not sure but from what I read, connecting the site with Github isn't possible with WordPress.com. Does that mean the only option that we have is to manually upload any changes?

I'm a front-end dev, and we don't have any back-end dev volunteers so any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Relative to a dev, changing your hosting (even if it means forgoing paid hosting) is chump change.     Also, remember you will probably want to handle the database as well as the files.

Comment: I suggested this option but their site has already passed the deadline for a refund so they opted to keep it and stay with a business plan. I guess we will be sticking with this in the meantime. @davidgo

Comment: Never used it, not a recommendaton - but maybe https://versionpress.com/